# Dividir uma tabela para optimizar o seu espaço na página

Tags: php, html, loop

Tenho um `array` e com ele faço uma tabela com comparação de dados, essa tabela fica muito grande (tem que rolar muito o `scroll` do rato) e no lado direito da tela fica em branco.

**Script:**

```
reset($quebra);

while (key( $quebra) !== null) {

  // print("Numero do Array".key($quebra)."-- Resultado do Array ".current($quebra))."<br>\r\n";

  $row = explode (" " , key($quebra) . "=" . current($quebra));
  $posicao3 = strpos($row[0], '=');

  if (isset($ocupados[substr($row[0],$posicao3+1,4)]))
    $dadosweb .= "<tr ><td bgcolor=#FF0000>".substr($row[0],$posicao3+1,4)."</td><td >".$row[20]."</td>";
  else
    $dadosweb .= "<tr><td >".substr($row[0],$posicao3+1,4)."</td><td >".$row[20]."</td>";

  $dadosweb .= "<td ></td><td ></td></tr>";

  next($quebra);
}
```

## Pergunta

Como posso dividir essa tabela para ocupar melhor a pagina ?

Comment: Como assim "quebrar a tabela"?

Comment: Mostra a estrutura de sua array, e se possível poste um link da forma que está sendo feito.

Comment: Aproveitei a edição do @perdeu e melhorei um pouco a informação na pergunta. Contudo, para entendermos melhor o que é perguntado, deverás elaborar o problema, colocaste o ciclo que está a preparar o HTML, mas queres que esse ciclo processe apenas metade dos registos encontrados? É isso? E a outra metade vai para outro lugar? **Nota:** Uma captura de tela do resultado que estás a ter e uma descrição do que gostarias que ficasse pode ir um longo caminho no entendimento do teu objectivo.

Comment: Talvez você possa adicionar: `<p>` ao lado do `<tr>`, e assim criar outra tabela com o `<td>`, não sei se é isso que você quer fazer.

Comment: Segue o link, https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-zvM49q_2L-E/UupD-BoymqI/AAAAAAAAAcA/POLyRXRhbYY/w894-h503-no/Captura+de+tela+de+2014-01-30+10%253A21%253A20.png

Quero que essa tabela use todo o estaço da pagina, tipo, contar o current e a cada 20 começar outra tabela, mas os dados não podem repetir.

Comment: @isac borgert vc quer centralizar a tabela e 'paginar' a consulta?

Comment: Quebre ela colocando limitação de `<tr>` você pode fazer isso tanto puxando tudo para a esquerda ou outra tabela ao lado.

Comment: Eu quero que as duas colunas que contém dados sejam divididas em umas 6 colunas, para ocupar melhor o espaço da pagina e não precisar rolar muito o scrool, e os dados não podem aparecer repetidos na tela.

Comment: @user3253024 como eu faço isso? não posso repetir os dados na tela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o [array_chunk](http://br.php.net/array_chunk) com [foreach](http://br.php.net/foreach):

```
$tabelas = array_chunk($quebra, 20, true) // 20 = numero de linhas por tabela.
foreach ($tabelas as $tabela) {
    $dadosweb .= "<table>";
    foreach ($tabela as $key => $current) {
        $row = explode (" " , $key . "=" . $current);
        $posicao3 = strpos($row[0], '=');
        $dadosweb .= "<tr>";

        if (isset($ocupados[substr($row[0],$posicao3+1,4)])) {
            $dadosweb .= "<td bgcolor=#FF0000>".substr($row[0],$posicao3+1,4)."</td><td >".$row[20]."</td>";
        } else {
            $dadosweb .= "<td>".substr($row[0],$posicao3+1,4)."</td><td >".$row[20]."</td>";
        }

        $dadosweb .= "</tr>";
    }
    $dadosweb .= "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Parece + - isso mesmo, vou tentar, valeu